# Auto populate fields in Word from drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, dropdown

The thing is to have a dropdown list from which I can choose the name and I need that other fields in Word file will be filled with contact data of this person. The data comes from an Excel file which I managed to connect and populate the dropdown lists. I am stuck and I have no idea how to auto populate the fields by choosing the name. For now I have 5 records in the database but there will be more. I have already started my adventure with programming and probably the things that I ask for are simple but anyway, here is what I have made by searching in lots of tutorials:

```
Sub Document_Open()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application, xlWkBk As Excel.Workbook
  Dim StrWkBkNm As String, StrWkShtNm As String, LRow As Long

  StrWkBkNm = "D:\Users\Magda91\Desktop\filename.xlsx"
  StrWkShtNm = "Sheet1"
  If Dir(StrWkBkNm) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cannot find the designated workbook: " & StrWkBkNm, vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  With xlApp
    'Hide our Excel session
    .Visible = False
    ' Open the workbook
    Set xlWkBk = .Workbooks.Open(FileName:=StrWkBkNm, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
    ' Process the workbook.
    With xlWkBk
      If SheetExists(StrWkShtNm) = True Then
        With .Worksheets(StrWkShtNm)

          Dim MyMatrix1(1 To 5, 1 To 5)
          Dim i As Integer, j As Integer 
          For i = 1 To 5 
            For j = 1 To 5 
              MyMatrix1(i, j) = .Cells(i + 1, j).Value
            Next j
          Next i

         ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("TechnicalContactName")(1).DropdownListEntries.Clear
         ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Position1")(1).DropdownListEntries.Clear
         ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Phone1")(1).DropdownListEntries.Clear
         ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Mobile1")(1).DropdownListEntries.Clear
         ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Email1")(1).DropdownListEntries.Clear
         For i = 1 To 4
           ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("TechnicalContactName")(1).DropdownListEntries.Add _
            Text:=Trim(MyMatrix1(i, 1))
           ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Position1")(1).DropdownListEntries.Add _
            Text:=Trim(MyMatrix1(i, 2))
           ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Phone1")(1).DropdownListEntries.Add _
            Text:=Trim(MyMatrix1(i, 3))
           ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Mobile1")(1).DropdownListEntries.Add _
            Text:=Trim(MyMatrix1(i, 4))
           ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Email1")(1).DropdownListEntries.Add _
            Text:=Trim(MyMatrix1(i, 5))
         Next

       End With
     Else
       MsgBox "Cannot find the designated worksheet: " & StrWkShtNm, vbExclamation
     End If
     .Close False
   End With
   .Quit
 End With

 ' Release Excel object memory
 Set xlWkBk = Nothing: Set xlApp = Nothing
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function SheetExists(SheetName As String) As Boolean
  SheetExists = False
  On Error GoTo NoSuchSheet
  If Len(Sheets(SheetName).Name) > 0 Then SheetExists = True
  NoSuchSheet:
End Function
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you mean by "field". I get the feeling you mean "content controls", as in the other dropdowns? ("Fields" in Word are a very specific thing and it's confusing when you use the term for anything else.) Do you really need 5 dropdowns? If the user should choose the *name*, why not have the others as text content controls? Note also that an OLE DB connection would be more efficient than opening the workbook, especially if you're going to have a lot of entries. Workbooks can take a long time to open...

Comment: You are totally right! For now I have all dropdowns, but I will try to do it with textboxes, it might be better.

Comment: So, are you OK for the moment, working on using plain text or rich text content controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to a field  where you would select Insert->Quick Parts-> Field -> Document Automation.

If so and with

> TechnicalContactName fields as  TechnicalContactName
>   Position fields as  PositionField
>   Phone fields as  PhoneField
>   Mobile fields as  MobileField
>   Email fields as  EmailField

I also assume that you want to use the respective Position, Phone, Mobile and Email from the "Technical Contact" and not the different selections in each Dropdownlist.

Once the **Technical Contact** has been selected then run this code. It can also be assigned to a Button you have added to the Document.

```
 Sub PopulatingFieldsFromDropDownBox()

      Dim TechnicalContactDropDownList As ContentControl
      Set TechnicalContactDropDownList = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("TechnicalContactName").Item(1)

      'Getting the selected entry Name
      Dim SelectedTechnicalContact As String
      SelectedTechnicalContact = TechnicalContactDropDownList.Range.Text

      'Getting the Dropdownbox index number for TechnicalContact box
      Dim ListEntryNumber As Long
      For ListEntryNumber = 1 To TechnicalContactDropDownList.DropdownListEntries.Count

           If SelectedTechnicalContact = TechnicalContactDropDownList.DropdownListEntries(ListEntryNumber).Text Then
                Exit For
           End If

      Next ListEntryNumber

      'The Number is brackets needs to be one more that the amount for DropDownLists you have
      'Because the array actually starts at 0
      Dim TechnicalContactArray(5) As Variant

      TechnicalContactArray(1) = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("TechnicalContactName").Item(1).DropdownListEntries(ListEntryNumber).Text
      TechnicalContactArray(2) = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Position1").Item(1).DropdownListEntries(ListEntryNumber).Text
      TechnicalContactArray(3) = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Phone1").Item(1).DropdownListEntries(ListEntryNumber).Text
      TechnicalContactArray(4) = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Mobile1").Item(1).DropdownListEntries(ListEntryNumber).Text
      TechnicalContactArray(5) = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Email1").Item(1).DropdownListEntries(ListEntryNumber).Text

      Dim CurrentField As Field
      For Each CurrentField In ActiveDocument.Fields

           'Sending the Correct data to the various fields
           If InStr(1, CurrentField.Code.Text, "TechnicalContactName") > 0 Then
                CurrentField.Result.Text = TechnicalContactArray(1)
           ElseIf InStr(1, CurrentField.Code.Text, "PositionField") > 0 Then
                CurrentField.Result.Text = TechnicalContactArray(2)
           ElseIf InStr(1, CurrentField.Code.Text, "Phone") > 0 Then
                CurrentField.Result.Text = TechnicalContactArray(3)
           ElseIf InStr(1, CurrentField.Code.Text, "Mobile") > 0 Then
                CurrentField.Result.Text = TechnicalContactArray(4)
           ElseIf InStr(1, CurrentField.Code.Text, "Email") > 0 Then
                CurrentField.Result.Text = TechnicalContactArray(5)
           End If

      Next CurrentField

 End Sub
```